# Scala Right, Left decomposing difficulties

Tags: scala

I do some `scala` exercises. I have got a method:

```
def getDepartment: (Either[String, Employee]) => Either[String, String] = ???
```

I need implement body. Method parameter data examples:

1. Right(Employee("Joe", "Finances", Some("Julie")))
2. Right(Employee("Mary", "IT", None))
3. Left("Employee not found")

Method should return next:

1. Right("Finances")
2. Right("IT")
3. Left("Employee not found")

So I'm adding body:

```
def getDepartment: (Either[String, Employee]) => Either[String, String] = _ match {
  case _: Left[String, Employee] =>
    println(s"Left: " + _)
    _ // unbound placeholder parameter - compilation error
  case _: Right[String, Employee] =>
    println(s"Right: " + _)
    _ // unbound placeholder parameter - compilation error
  case _ =>
    println(s" " + _)
    _ // unbound placeholder parameter - compilation error
}
```

I know that my implementation is incorrect because of compilation errors all the time. It seems I'm not experienced to implement required solution.

Regarding method declaration I found information is [scala tutorial](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations.html#function-values). But I have not got any helpful ideas how to map `_` into required Type. Possible somebody can help fix my compilation error of propose better way for body implementation.

### P.S.

Solution should be implemented over `Optional` without error handling.

### P.S.2

Task was taken from [online resource](https://www.scala-exercises.org/fp_in_scala/handling_error_without_exceptions). First task in Exercise 4.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need to give names to the matched values in the first two cases, and the third one isn't useful (technically, it can match if the argument is `null`, but that's an error on the caller's side, let them deal with it):

   ```
   def getDepartment: (Either[String, Employee]) => Either[String, String] = _ match {
     case left: Left[String, Employee] =>
       println(s"Left: " + left)
       ???
     case right: Right[String, Employee] =>
       println(s"Right: " + right)
       ???
   }
   ```

   Note that both `???`s need to be replaced by something which has type `Either[String, String]` and uses `left`/`right`.
2. But it's better to match `Left` and `Right` using extractors:

   ```
   def getDepartment: (Either[String, Employee]) => Either[String, String] = _ match {
     case Left(string) =>
       ??? // use string ("contents" of the Left) here
     case Right(employee) =>
       ??? // use employee here
   }
   ```
3. There is a special case for functions of the form `_ match { ... }`, which allows you to write simply

   ```
   def getDepartment: (Either[String, Employee]) => Either[String, String] = {
     case Left(string) =>
       ??? // use string ("contents" of the Left) here
     case Right(employee) =>
       ??? // use employee here
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution is (...it is confirmed in exercise resource also):

```
def getDepartment: (Either[String, Employee]) => Either[String, String] = _.map(_.department)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do that with fold too.

```
def getDepartment: Either[String, Employee] =>  Either[String, String] = _.fold(Left(_), a => Right(a.department))
```

Update:
Playing with Either, I came out with this:

```
implicit class EitherAsSuffix[T](v: T) { 
  def asRight = Right(v); 
  def asLeft = Left(v);
  // edited again
  def asRight_[L]: Either[L, T] = Right(v)
  def asLeft_[R]: Either[T, R] = Left(v)
  // so that we can, just as a proof of concept, val n = 4.toLeft_[String] 
}
```

Then we can

```
def getDepartment: Either[String, Employee] =>  Either[String, String] = _.fold(_.asLeft, _.department.asRight)
```